# Creating a nested hash from ActiveRecord object in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, json, activerecord, hash

```
require "active_record"

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter  => 'mysql2',
  :database => '<db_name>',
  :username => '<username>',
  :password => '<password>',
  :host     => 'localhost')

ActiveRecord::Base.pluralize_table_names = false

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :location_channels
    has_many :channels, :through => :location_channels
end

class Channel < ActiveRecord::Base  
    has_many :location_channels
    has_many :locations, :through => :location_channels
end

class LocationChannel < ActiveRecord::Base  
    belongs_to :location
    belongs_to :channel
end

locations = Location.all

hash = {} # hash initialization

locations.each do |location|
    hash["location"] = location[:name]
        puts "#{location[:name]} has #{location.channels.size} channels:"
            location.channels.each do |channel|
                puts "--> #{channel[:name]}"
            end
        puts
end

puts hash
```

***Final goal is to create one*** `JSON` ***file***.

So I decided it'll be easier to create `JSON` from `Hash object`.

As in the code above, I'm able to access nested documents via JOIN table called `LocationChannel` class and I'm trying to figure out how to create a `Hash object` what will look like:

```
{ 
  ["location" => "A", "channels" => {"1","2","3"}], 
  ["location" => "B", "channels" => {"1","2"}], 
  ["location" => "C", "channels" => {"4","5","6"}]
}
```

where `"A"`, `"B"` and `"C"` - locations name and `"1"`, `"2"`, etc. - represents channels name.

And the current code prints out only the last record like:

```
{"location"=>"A"}
```

Please correct me how should Hash look like if the sample above is wrong.

**UPDATE 1**

Thanks to @jonsnow for point out the hash format.

Hash format should be:

```
{ :locations =>
    [
       { name: a, channels: [1,2,3]}, 
       { name: b, channels: [1,2]},
       { name: c, channels: [4,5,6]}
    ]
}
```

Comment: array never store element like this `["location" => "A", "channels" => {"1","2","3"}]` .

Comment: a Hash can never look like what you are expecting. There are no `key => value` pairs in your hash

Comment: firs pair is `"location" => "A"`, 2nd pair: does it have to look `"channels" => ["1","2","3"]` ?

Comment: No oscar, your o/p arrays are in improper format, maybe your o/p should be look like this, 

{ :locations => [{ name: a, channels: [1,2]}, { name: b, channels: [1,2] } ].

Comment: @jon snow - Thanks, updated with correction.

Comment: @jonsnow didn't you forget closing curly brackets in your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for your updated hash,

```
hash = { locations: [] } # hash initialization

locations.each do |location|
  hash[:locations] << { name: location.name,
  channels:  location.channels.pluck(:name) }
end
```

Comment: `in `block in <main>': undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

Comment: Opps, ans is updated. change `hash["locations"]` to `hash[:locations]`

Comment: Cool, worked! :) Thanks a lot! I believe many people will benefit from this solution.